# Operation not permitted and permission denied

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions

My mac version is 10.12.2.

I'm trying to install R studio and a number of other softwares, but it doesn't work. I suspect it's because of permission issues - my mac doesn't allow them to create directories during installing.

```
~$ pwd
/Users/biona001
~$ mkdir fdsa
mkdir: fdsa: Operation not permitted
```

but if I'm in a higher director, it says something different

```
~$ cd ../
Users$ pwd
/Users
Users$ mkdir fdsa
mkdir: fdsa: Permission denied
```

and if I move into a lower directory, it works

```
Users$ cd biona001/Documents/
Documents$ mkdir fdsa
Documents$
```

I googled almost everything without finding anything that worked, including the one where I boot my mac into this weird mode and type some command. I should be the administrator of this mac.

Answer (score 1):

R Studio is installed by dragging the application to your applications folder. It requires R to be installed. R can be installed from a package, so you don't need the command line.

The 'administrator' on the mac, does not have permission to write files or create folders anywhere. It's not a good idea in any case.

If it's absolutely necessary, you must enable 'root' and login as root. But this is *not* necessary to use R Studio and R.

Enabling root access without knowing exactly what you are doing is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: But why can't I create folder inside my user account (biona001)? Shouldn't I normally be able to? Even with sudo mkdir I can't. Also I already installed R

Comment: type 'whoami' on the command line when the mkdir fails and show us the result.

Comment: biona001    <--- that's it. If it helps I had a question last year, never resolved, and I think it's fundamentally the same issue. I was able to survive without using terminal from then until now, but I can't anymore

Comment: show us the output of ls -la ..   (from your home directory, ie- where the problem is)

Comment: This is the output: 
drwxr-xr-x+ 72 biona001  staff  2448 May 22  2016 /Users/biona001

Comment: if I do    sudo ls -ld /Users/biona001

Comment: the + indicates extended permissions on the user folder. check them with the finder (do a Get Info on the folder biona001) . See what the read/write permissions are set to at the bottom.

Comment: There are three users, biona001 with read and write permission. The other two are staff and everyone with read only.

Comment: well, i'm baffled. Here's some notes about extended permissions. http://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-report-operation-not-permitted-on-os-x (otoh, this has nothing to do with R, right?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "operation not permitted" issue on MacOS Sierra.

Looking at the user's home folder in Finder as John Elemans recommended, showed that the home folder was locked. Unchecked the locked checkbox in finder and was able to create a subfolder in the user's home folder via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also faced same problm in MacOS while opening R studio , it produces a pop-up error saying

> File Listing Error, Error navigating to ~/Desktop: Operation not permitted.

so waht u have to do

- open R studio
- you may find RStudio next to apple icon Click over there
- Then click on Service setting
- Then Click on Accessibility

and then

- Click on Restore default

Now when u open R studio again it will ask
to all permission for folder etc

- click allow

U can also check sysytem preference by clicking on mac icon

> apple icon>System setting > Security & Privacy > Accessibility > .....